# Update form based on dropdown selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to `Rails` and I'm trying to figure out how to change either the fields in the form, or the form itself, based on the selection of a drop down menu. I have thought about using `AJAX`, or about embedded Ruby within the form. Any direction would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously there will be javascripts involved at some point.

I think there are 2 solutions for you to choose from:

1. using ajax to fetch the new data to change your form upon dropdown changes
2. loading everything you need from the first time (when landing to the page) and then displayhing/hiding things only using javascript

Starting from this, I suppose your decision will be made depending if you want/can afford loading everything you need from the beginning... and if not you'll probably go with ajax.

Let us know if you need some more details. : )